# How to setup GCE development server using android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

Just install new **android studio 3.0** and I cannot find **google cloud endpoint** in android studio module.

Please how to set up Google Cloud Endpoint with the latest **android studio 3.0**

Comment: check out this note, and change in project gradle
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating-android

Comment: I follow the links but I am not able to setup GCE. following also these steps are no more available in android studio 3.0 https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

Answer (score 2):

In This link the **Read.MD** That is Provided By **GoogleCloudPlatform** specifically for **endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin** has a few modifications due to issue they have found ... It Worked For me as i had the same issue , do the modifications until this line "If you have a particularly complicated buildscript classpath bringing in a lot of dependencies with cryptic error messages like"

clean and build your app and try to run your backend module

here is the link : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md

you might face an issue of jsr305 or so ...

add configurations.all in your build.gradle (app) as below

```
android {
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force    'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```

you might another issue called 
Can't start process working directory .............................  exploded-app folder doesn't exist

in order to solve this

modify the backend/backend.iml

Change:

```
<option name="WAR_DIR" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build/exploded-app" />
```

To:

```
<option name="WAR_DIR" value="$MODULE_DIR$/build/exploded-backend" />
```

if you faced anything let me know i have been going through hit and miss so i faced some issues that might occur to you

note: check the **"Android Studio" section** specially the "**Run**" part because it's telling you that you need to  run the local development server using the gradle task **appengineStart** which starts the development server in non-blocking mode